# Universal image loader - UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

So, I get following error:

```
UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [12258]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))
```

when i pass this image file to display image:

```
file:///data/data/com.proba.santaapp/files/JPEG_20141014_213921_.jpg
```

Anybody know how to use UIL library to display image file in app data folder?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code:

```
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse("file_path"));
```

Universal image loader is generally used when u have urls not for file:

Comment: thanks, I already use this, but I need do this with UIL library

Answer (score 0):

Use drawable only if you really need it! Always consider the native way to load drawables - `ImageView.setImageResource(...)` instead of using of `ImageLoader`.